# CreateFileMapping size limit in a 64-bit process

Tags: windows, winapi, file-mapping

Is there a size limit to the file mapping object? The reason I'm asking is that there is a mentioning of 2GB limit somewhere in MSDN (lost the track..) and I also checked this sample, which also expects 2GB size limit:

https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/CreateFileMapping/cpp-createfilemapping-function-examples.html

But I tried on a 40GB file with no problems on newest Win 10, so I'm a bit worried if there wasn't some limitation on older Windows for example.

Comment: for section size used 8bytes, so in 64-bit process - limit only by system resources

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-a-file-mapping-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 2GB limit for file mappings. You can boot 32-bit Windows with the 3GB option or when a 32-bit process running on a 64-bit system, you get the full 4GB if the correct [PE flag](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050601-24/?p=35483) is set. All these limits are theoretical and you will never reach them in practice.

How large of a view you can map depends on two things;

1. The contiguous range of free addresses in your processes address space.
2. Available kernel memory for keeping track of the memory pages.

The first one is the big limit on 32-bit systems since the address space of your process is shared with system libraries, 3rd-party libraries (anti-virus, injected "tweaking" tools etc.), the PEB and TEBs, the system region, thread stacks and memory reserved by hardware. This will often put you well below 2GB. Any design requiring more than 500MB should probably be changed to only map in specific smaller ranges as needed.

[For a 64-bit process on 64-bit Windows, the virtual address space is the 128-terabyte range 0x000'00000000 through 0x7FFF'FFFFFFFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces) ([KB889654](https://web.archive.org/web/20071220123333/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889654) claims 8 TB but that only applies to [< Windows 8.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150605-00/?p=45441)). Any usable range is going to be smaller but you can assume a couple of terabyte at least. 40GB is no problem and not enough to run into problems with low system resources either.